# How do i bind data into xrRichTextbox in Devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have added XRRichTextbox into XtraReport, i just want to bind HTML into RichTextbox

how do i bind HTML in to RichTextbox  in Devexpress ?

Comment: Please Explain your Question more Clearly or Provide some code for your effor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Html Databinding property

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i tried to bind an HTML Tabs.. like <h1> John </h1>, it display's with <h1> tag..